# Unable to start nginx pods with kubernetes master on one Virtualbox guest VM and kubernetes node on another VM

Tags: nginx, kubernetes

I have successfully installed Kubernetes using kubeadm. I am running two VirtualBox VMs, one for the K8s master an another one for a node.

**Kubernetes Master**

```
sudo kubectl get nodes
NAME                STATUS    ROLES     AGE       VERSION
kubernetes-master   Ready     master    1h        v1.10.2
kubernetes-node1    Ready     <none>    1h        v1.10.2
```

I can correctly ssh both into the master (`ssh 192.168.56.3`) and node (`ssh 192.168.56.4`).

I want to deploy nginx in the cluster using this deployment file:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1 # for versions before 1.9.0 use apps/v1beta2
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-deployment
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  replicas: 2 
  template: 
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx:latest
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
```

I am ssh'd into the master node, where I execute: `sudo kubectl apply -f nginx-deployment.yml`.

I see that the pods are stuck on PENDING:

```
sudo kubectl get pods --all-namespaces
NAMESPACE     NAME                                        READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
default       nginx-deployment-64ff85b579-5vkdz           0/1       Pending   0          4m
default       nginx-deployment-64ff85b579-w84lf           0/1       Pending   0          4m
```

This is the describe option for one of them:

```
sudo kubectl describe pod nginx-deployment-64ff85b579-5vkdz 
Name:           nginx-deployment-64ff85b579-5vkdz
Namespace:      default
Node:           <none>
Labels:         app=nginx
                pod-template-hash=2099416135
Annotations:    <none>
Status:         Pending
IP:             
Controlled By:  ReplicaSet/nginx-deployment-64ff85b579
Containers:
  nginx:
    Image:        nginx:latest
    Port:         80/TCP
    Host Port:    0/TCP
    Environment:  <none>
    Mounts:
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from default-token-7glwn (ro)
Conditions:
  Type           Status
  PodScheduled   False 
Volumes:
  default-token-7glwn:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  default-token-7glwn
    Optional:    false
QoS Class:       BestEffort
Node-Selectors:  <none>
Tolerations:     node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute for 300s
                 node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute for 300s
Events:
  Type     Reason            Age               From               Message
  ----     ------            ----              ----               -------
  Warning  FailedScheduling  8s (x22 over 5m)  default-scheduler  0/2 nodes are available: 1 node(s) had taints that the pod didn't tolerate, 1 node(s) were not ready, 1 node(s) were out of disk space.
```

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well... for some reason my node was down. I just had to restart the kubelet service and now it works:

```
systemctl restart kubelet.service
```

Comment: Didnt Work for Me. The error though remains the same
"1 node(s) had taints that the pod didn't tolerate, 1 node(s) were not ready."

Help.!